Recursive grid search of a sorted matrix
I have an algorithm that is checking whether the given key is present in the 2D sorted array where each row is sorted in an ascending order from left to right and each column is sorted in an ascending order from top to bottom.

Is there a way to modify it so that it wouldn't be simply returning True or False, but rather the original indicies (i, j), where the element was located in the matrix?
If the element is not present it should be returning (-1, -1). What would be the time complexity of such a modified algorithm? Is it possible to do with no extra space?

Hi Yan, at CS.SE, we also expect you to show the efforts that you make to solve the problem. It is not advised to simply copy and paste the question. :D

Apart from the minor case mismatch in the recursive calls, there are missing arguments (dimensions) as well.

Instead of passing slices of $M$, pass absolute indices alongside. Ofcourse you need to adjust the indices in the body as well to derive the relative indices used in the recursive calls. In this way you would have access to original indices whenever there is a match. The rest of the details is already laid out in Inuyasha Yagami's answer.

Wherever, you are returning true, return the indices $[i,j]$ instead.
Wherever, you are returning false, return the indices $[-1,-1]$ instead.
